# how to export sdf file from onshape?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, sdf, librviz

I had problems extracting urdf file from solidworks, because I am working on a delta robot (closed chain). So I redesigned the robot in onshape which I read that it can be extracted directly as sdf. However, I can't figure out how to do that.